# why there is a null parameter in the constructor when decompile the Parcelable class in android studio

Tags: java, android

The source is like this :

```
public class NavUIStatus implements Parcelable {
    public static final Creator<NavUIStatus> CREATOR = new 
        Creator<NavUIStatus() 
        {
            public NavUIStatus createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new NavUIStatus(in);
        }

        public NavUIStatus[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NavUIStatus[size];
        }
    };

    private NavUIStatus(Parcel in){
        ...
        in.readTypedList(this.laneInfos, LaneInfo.CREATOR);
    }
}
```

and when decompile this class in the android studio, the class is shown as this:

```
public class NavUIStatus implements Parcelable {

    public static final Creator<NavUIStatus> CREATOR = new Creator() {
        public NavUIStatus createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new NavUIStatus(in, null);
        }

        public NavUIStatus[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NavUIStatus[size];
        }
    };
}
```

so, why there is null parameter in the NavUIStatus(in, null) ?

thanks.

Comment: did it change the constructor of `NavUIStatus` too?

Comment: @ Vladyslav Matviienko  no it didn't change the constructor, at least as saw in the studio:            private NavUIStatus(Parcel in) {
        this.laneInfos = new ArrayList();
        this.currentSegmentIndex = in.readInt();
        ........
        in.readTypedList(this.laneInfos, LaneInfo.CREATOR);
    }